# HERE Maps Android SDK - no navigation instructions or arrows because of stop waypoints

Tags: java, android, navigation, here-api

I have an Android app using the HERE Premium SDK. My route's waypoints are recorded automatically by tracking someone driving the route. As a result, some waypoints are in or near junctions. The waypoints have to be stop waypoints because each waypoint is important and have to be done in order. When there's a stop waypoint in or near a turn, the direction that shows which way to turn isn't shown until the waypoint is reached. This is a huge issue because the driver needs to know where to turn in advance. It works if the waypoint is a via waypoint, but not if it's a stop waypoint.

Here are screenshots to prove what I'm saying:

[Turn 1 - Via waypoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzpUn.png)

[Turn 1 - Stop waypoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehmE5.png)

[Turn 2 - Via waypoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbpLU.png)

[Turn 2 - Stop waypoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5IY.png)

As you can see, when they're via waypoints, the arrows display perfectly fine. When they're stop waypoints, the arrow doesn't display until the driver is already in the junction. As there are two possible roads to go and both are blue, the driver has no idea where to go.

How do you make the navigation display the instructions before hitting the stop waypoint, like it does for via waypoints?

Comment: From the pictures this looks like the Premium SDK 3.x, not the Navigate SDK 4.x, correct?

Comment: @leopectus Yes. Does the Navigate SDK solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure, I was just trying to verify which version of the SDK you are using. I don't know the answer myself, but maybe I can find someone who does.

Comment: For the HERE SDK for Android (Navigate Edition), rendered direction arrows are not yet available, but they are planned and should come in one of the next editions. However, as a driver, you probably don't look at the map arrows. Instead, it's recommended to add voice instructions or a bigger display that clearly shows the directions as part of the next maneuver. Both is already possible for the Navigate Edition and should also work for stopover waypoints.

Comment: @Datasun the problem is, the instruction doesn't either show or do a voice instruction for the maneuver PAST the stop waypoint, like it does for via waypoints. are you saying it does on the Navigate edition?